# java Point type subtraction

Tags: java, point

I'm trying to implement this subtraction method

[image: Type Point subtraction]

Problem is when I try to use it it give me an error here's my code

```
public Point subtract( Point p1, Point p2) {
    Point p3 = new Point();
    p3 = p1 - p2;   ////getting error here
    return p3;
}


public int isHorizonatalCollision(Objects object) {
    int tru = 0;
    int leftColli = 1;
     Point eqp;
     eqp =  subtract(posi(), nposi());

        if (eqp == objposi(object) )
        {
            return leftColli;
        }
        return tru; 
    }
```

Comment: `it give me an error here's my code` - what error do you get? And from which package did you import `Point`?

Comment: How do you think `p3 = p1 - p2;` should work, and why do you think it should work?

Comment: You cannot directly subtract two Point object using "-"

Comment: it seems that as per documentation of `Point` class, method name is `subtract` so why you using minus sign ( - ) on those objects? You need to paste a bit more detail about your `Point` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static Point subtract(Point p1, Point p2) {
    return new Point(p1.x - p2.x, p1.y - p2.y);
}
```

Or

```
public static Point subtract(Point p1, Point p2) {
    return new Point(p1.getX() - p2.getX(), p1.getY() - p2.getY());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Java does not allow operator overloading, so you cannot subtract your custom classes in Java.

Subtraction is only valid on built-in numeric primitives and their object counterparts (`int`, `double`, `float`, ... and `Integer`, `Double`, ...). Java has no way to know what `-` on your `Point` class should do.

If the semantic of your subtraction is to subtract each coordinate respectively, you'll have to code it that way:

```
class Point {
    int x;
    int y;

    ...

    public Point subtract(Point another) {
        return new Point(this.x - another.x, this.y - another.y);
    }
}
```